# How to launch an Android application under current application?

Tags: android, android-intent, background, android-activity

I have two Android apps that communicate with each other through BroadcastReceiver. But if the second receiver application wasn’t started, the first one just sits there... The second application, once started, needs to continue running indefinitely, but not interrupt the first application by popping up over it. So I need a way to start the second application through the first one, BUT the screen has to continue showing the first application.

Through the first app, I check for presence of the second application, and if it's found and is not running, I start the application:

```
Intent SecondApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app2");
startActivity(SecondApp);
```

But this brings up the second application to the screen ontop of the first one. So I need a solution to ether

1) Start the second application under the fist one

Or

2) Put the current first application immediately one on top of the second app

What’s the best solution here, and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help. The command `finish()` surprisingly does get rind of the UI, but doesn’t kill the application.

There was still the issue of only “minimizing” it when I start it from scratch through the first app, and run the second application normally in all other cases. So I added a boolean flag to the first application intent:

```
Intent SecondApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app2");
SecondApp.putExtra("StartMinimized",true);
startActivity(SecondApp);
```

In the second application onCreate I put this code in:

```
Intent glob_intent = getIntent();
boolean startmini = glob_intent.getBooleanExtra("StartMinimized",false);
glob_intent.putExtra("StartMinimized",false);
if(startmini)
{
    finish();
    Toast.makeText(this,"L",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Inform that app started
}
```

Now when starting the first application, the second application only flashes a white screen for a moment. I think this is good enough.

I found that substituting `finish();` with `super.moveTaskToBack(true);` also works, but can cause glitching later. This way I personally started the second application twice, or caused the introduction dialog to not display when making the application one instance only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your second application has a service running in background and when you do the startActivity(SecondApp); pass some parameters with the intent, and in the second app read this parameter and just call finish after starting the service if that parameter is present.

Comment: I guess forcing it to end after the job is done, is one way to do it. But it won't work in my case, as there can be multiple "first" applications, so the second one will be started and will keep on running.

Comment: But if you have the service running in the background, the second app will continue running in background, finish() will just close the UI.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I'm surprised the method called FINISH doesn't actually kill the application.